# How to capture "Enter" keyboard event on dynamically created lightning:input component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery

Official [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) for `lightning:input` did not show any keyboard event attributes yet. I have a dynamically created input form and I want to call a controller's method after hitting the enter key on a input text element.

I tried using `jQuery` to bind the input element with `keyup` method, but it doesn't seems to be working for me.

**Component**

```
 <aura:component>
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jQueryLib + '/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'}" 
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <p>Dynamically created input Text</p>
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

**Controller.js**

```
 doInit : function(cmp, event, helper)
    {
        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:input",
            {
                "label": "First Name",
                "type": "text",
                "name":"testing",
                "class":"inputTestClass"
            },
            function(newText, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newText);
                    cmp.set("v.body", body);
                    console.log("I printed out after scripts loaded");
                }
                else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                    // Show offline error
                }
                else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                    // Show error message
                }
            }
        );                      
    },
  afterScriptsLoaded:function(component, event, helper)
  {
    console.log(jQuery(".inputTestClass").children().children("input"));  
    //returns nothing; 
    //expected an input element
    jQuery(".inputTestClass").children().children("input").keyup(function()
    {
            console.log("did I get it?") // Not printed on the console
        });    
   }
```

Its because, the `afterScriptsLoaded` is executed first before the `init` handler called.

Comment: this might be of help -> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147024/any-way-to-detect-keyup-and-keydown-events-not-using-an-input-field

Answer (score 1):

I think if you can store the input component using an `onfocus` event, you can then capture a keyboard event by either:

either attaching a listener to the `window` or wrapping everything in a span or div with a `onkeyup` event.

Markup:

```
<span onkeyup="{!c.handleKeyup}">
  <lightning:input label="Name" name="myname" onfocus="{!c.handleFocus}"/>
</span>
```

Controller:

```
handleFocus: function(component, event, helper) {
    var src = event.getSource();
    component.set("v.currentInput",src);
},

handleKeyup: function(component, event, helper) {

    //you have the relevant input + the keyboard event
    var currentInput = component.get("v.currentInput");

    if(event.key == 'Enter') {
      console.log(event);
        //do something
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Forgot to say, to add your focus handler to the dynamically created component, use `component.getReference()` to get a ref to the method. Eg in your component creation call, do something like this:

```
"lightning:input",
 {
   "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
   "onfocus": component.getReference("c.handleFocus"),
   "label": "your label",
   "name": "your name"
 },
```

In the `handleKeyup` method, you can then do whatever processing you need as you have both the keyboard event and the relevant component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't tried your method yet as I have found another work around using custom rendering in `renderer.js`. I'll post my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

After a fair amount of googling and with the help of other SFSE answers, using the concept of [Custom Renderer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm) I am able to achieve what I was hoping for.

**Step 1 :** I added an extra attribute to the component to check whether my jQuery has been loaded

```
   <aura:attribute name="scriptsLoaded" type="boolean" default="false" />
```

**Step 2**: I set the variable to true in the controller method

```
afterScriptsLoaded:function(component, event, helper)
{
     component.set("v.scriptsLoaded", true);
     // This will trigger the re-render code in the renderer.js  
}
```

**Step3**: In `renderer.js`

```
rerender: function(component, helper) 
{
        this.superRerender();
        var areScriptsLoaded = component.get("v.scriptsLoaded");
        if(areScriptsLoaded){
            helper.postRender(component);    
        } 
}
```

**Step4**: In `helper.js`

```
postRender:function(component){ 
jQuery(".inputTestClass").children().children("input").keyup($A.getCallback(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode === 13)
                {
                     console.log('Enter key clicked');
                }

          }));

 }
```

Always use [$A.getCallback()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm) for any components if you are modifying outside framework.

Comment: I'm surprised that works given that you are modifying a component. Normally that's not allowed with Locker Service on. What API version is this component?

Comment: And yes, I should have told you - you can't perform operations on elements in the init (or shortly after the init) as the elements are not guaranteed to be there yet. You could simplify your code here by leaving out the tag and overriding the `afterRender` method rather than the `reRender` method.

Comment: @CasparHarmer I'm a bit surprised too. I've activated the locker service in our org and it is on v39.

Comment: @CasparHarmer I've tried `afterRender` method initially by reading the doc but for some reason, `afterRender` method fires before the `afterScriptsLoaded` method. May be that's because the component in the question is actually a child of another parent component. I'm still trying to wrap my head around this whole flow of 'renderer.js'.

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't taken into account loading jquery. Do you actually need jQuery? I like this site: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: interesting, I'm gonna give it a try. Thanks for sharing the website.